# How do I get wordpress to use my custom css for video player on the mobile site?

Tags: android, css, iphone, wordpress, mobile

I am a bit of a newbie when using css. I have a wordpress theme that is mobile responsive and uses built in wordpress video player. The theme developer gave me some code to edit the video player to have my own play button and color bars.This is the code:

```
.mejs-overlay-button { background: url(my log url here) no-repeat!important; }
```

I added the code to the custom css option and the code worked well for my desktop site. But when it comes to the mobile site, wordpress ignores the custom play button and uses its own. Screenshots:
http://i60.tinypic.com/35hpqur.jpg, http://i57.tinypic.com/20fs1ax.jpg

It feels like something is overwriting my changes on the wordpress mobile player. The developer didn't know why. Please help.

PS: I was testing on an iPhone

Comment: do you have any link to see the codes?

Comment: Which codes do you want me to post? The custom css codes? The single-video.php?